# Regular Expression to select text within bracket (and the bracket)

Tags: regex

I'm new at regular expression. I've tried several website to help me build regex but I simply mostly fail even at the simplest scenario of regex.

This time, I just want to build a regex to help me search and replace string on Notepad++. I want to erase all the characters that start with `[` and ends with `]`, and replace them with empty string. So basically I want to find all the characters within brackets, and erase them all.

So if I have this string:

`[2015-05-08] ERROR [US Channel Store]: An exception occurred at index.php.`

I want it to become:

`ERROR : An exception occurred at index.php.`

By search the document with the regex and replace with empty string.

My best attempt at making the regex is this: `\[.*\]`. (The website said that the full regex will actually be `/\[.*\]/g`)

But on the preview, I find that the regex' result actually select the whole line.

Can someone point where the mistake(s) are? And can you give me the correct regex? A little explanation on my error way of thinking about regex would be very appreciated to help me learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your regex non-greedy (lazy):

```
/\[.*?\]/g
```

Or better to use negation:

```
/\[[^]]*\]/g
```

Comment: `/\[.*?\]/g` That actually works! Oh I see. I need to learn more about this greedy vs non-greedy thing. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. I know. But when I try to mark as accepted, the website said "you can do this after x minutes". Well, OK, I said. So to pass the time, I did my work. And then in the end I forgot to return here to check it. Sometimes I really hate the system here that prevents me to mark the answer as accepted within 10 minutes since the posting of question. Once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this regex: `/\[[^]]+\]/g`